# postgresql get folder creation date

Tags: postgresql

i am trying to get the date when the folder in the filesystem was created using SQL and I cannot find a way to do this. Can someone help me achieve this? This is what i have so far

```
WITH date_check AS (
    SELECT 
        tablename 

        ,
        (
            select oid from pg_database where datname='PROD'
        ) as dbid 


        ,(SELECT relfilenode FROM pg_class WHERE relname ILIKE tablename) filenode

    FROM PG_TABLES
    WHERE schemaname = 'DUMMY' )

SELECT 
    tablename 
    ,(
        SELECT creation 
        FROM pg_stat_file(
            './base/' || dbid || '/' || filenode 
        )
    ) as creation_time FROM date_check;
```

My goal is to get the time at which a PostgreSQL table was created.

Comment: What doesn't work about this? Is the file actually located at that path?

Comment: It finds the respective folder but how to get the folder creation date from the file system using plsql

Comment: Documentation says "file creation time stamp (Windows only)" https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE-TABLE Can I suggest you use export the data and use a different tool to find this info.

Comment: The point of this to get a table creation date . Please can you suggest a better way to do this ?

Comment: Like I said: export the file names, and use a tool such as `stat`. Are you using Windows or Linux or something else?

Comment: Using Linux . Apologies for my ignorance.. u mean export the related file node IDs to a txt file , get the timestamp and if older than let’s say 1 month then import to a temp table and delete related tables based on file node IDs?

Comment: Yes, but do note that many file systems popular on Linux do not store creation date

Comment: What do you mean? We using centos , if ls -ltr shows the modified date of a folder then how do I derive this info to correctly delete the table that does not meet the retention policy ?

Comment: Is there an another easier way to get a table creation date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get the creation timestamp of a table in PostgreSQL. You'll have to persist that information somewhere (perhaps in a table) when you create a table.

The file creation timestamp does not necessarily reflect the timestamp when the table was created. Operations like `VACUUM (FULL)`, `TRUNCATE` or certain `ALTER TABLE` will write a new file for the table. Also, do you want your table creation timestamp to change when the database is restored from backup?

Comment: These are user tables that a user creates for their own development and don’t use need them. In order to do some housekeeping , I was trying to set up a process that deletes user tables that is older than 3 months .. this was my goal

Comment: Yes, but as I detailed, the create timestamp of the file won't always give you that information. Why don't you record the timestamps in some kind of housekeeping table? That should be simple. You could for example use an event trigger for that.

Comment: But an event trigger is doable even l choose log “all” . I can’t filter just create stable statement. Also with choosing “all” there is going to be performance deg?

Comment: If there is a way to have a custom trigger that logs the table name & create timestamp , then can I get an example on how I can achieve this please ? Thanks

Comment: That's a different question. Also, this is not a code writing service.

Comment: Sorry - Im not asking but looking to get pointers of any existing working examples & not to write me a script .